# commandline to notify when an image is added/updated in private docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Is there a way/command to see when an image is added/updated in the private docker registry? I am trying to write a script which will keep on scanning the docker-registry and whenever a new image is pushed or any image is updated and uploaded to private registry with a different tag, it will notify me. Can someone help me out as how I should approach this?

Comment: Inotify on a directory should do it

Answer (score 1):

The registry has a [Notification system](https://docs.docker.com/registry/notifications/) that can call out to a HTTP service on an [Event](https://docs.docker.com/registry/notifications/#events)

You could write a simple http service to run locally and accept events, check for the ones you want and then do the notification. It's maybe 20 lines of javascript to do it in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) with [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) and [Nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#tldr-usage-example). But that's one more service you need to worry about.

If you are happy to have all your event information go out to a third party, it might be easier to use a service like [Zapier Webhooks](https://zapier.com/blog/how-use-zapier-webhooks/). Zapier allows you to trigger pretty much any type of action from the registries notification web requests.  The [IFTTT Maker channel](https://ifttt.com/maker) is the same type of thing but couldn't be used in this case as you would not be able to pick out the specific events you want to handle, they aim for simplicity over function.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I did used notifications, setup a flask server to receive the notifications and did received them. But for a single image upload, it sends out 4-5 notifications (maybe for each layer) and doesn't contain tag information. I tried to get the tag using the digest, but it seems like the digest works in different ways for different schemaVersions ( 1 and 2). Hence a bit confused as to how to extract the tag and right image-name from multiple notifications received.

Comment: Ah, looks like the digest dropped out of the registry API on v2: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14082. I think they changed the way digests were calculated between v1 and v2 too. v2 does it on layer content. v1 might have been on some layer metadata.

Comment: It looks like you can `GET /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>` with the digest to look up the tag? [registry api manifest](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#manifest)

Comment: Matt: http://pastebin.com/K9e9XNit this is what I get if the schemaVersion is 2. I am not sure how I can extract "tag" using this.

Comment: I see, so `tag` only comes up if you request with a tag? right then. The only other way I think that might be possible is using what the git issue suggests. You can map tags to digests from the `Docker-Content-Digest` header. Loop over [tags](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#tags) and for each tag request get the digest? It's not going to be scalable at all but might tide you over until the API is fixed.  Then you could check each events digest to see if they match. simple! =/

Comment: I got it what you are saying. So, essentially get the image-name from the notifications, then get all the tags associated with that image using a separate request. Next, take each tag, download its manifest, and then check which manifest contains the same digest as the one received in previous request. I will try this and see how it goes.